# Code snippet library for a team

Tags: collaboration, code-snippets

I would like a general purpose code snippets library, that I could use to store bits of code for any language, organized in folders. When any developer on the network adds a snippet, it should get transferred to others.

How can I do this simply? Any app that could be used for sharing libraries of text should be okay too.

Comment: For reference: http://www.refactory.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code Warehouse](http://www.xcca.com/downloads.html) is the most extensive source code snippets manager. Code Warehouse is multi-user ready, which means that an organization’s entire development team can share a central code library and benefit from code that is already written and tested.

[alt text http://www.xcca.com/cwbig.png](http://www.xcca.com/cwbig.png)

Comment: how easy is it to setup Code Warehouse on a windows server for my whole team to use?

Comment: broken link, returns 404

Answer (score 3):

That's called "a wiki".

We use a Sharepoint Wiki page for exactly this purpose ... that way code instructions and examples can be included in the same place.

Comment: We're enslaved to Microsoft where I work - so we're just using the Sharepoint Wiki pages. It has a nice WYSIWYG editor for them. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A wiki is definitely the way to go but why stop there? Why not go with an issue tracking system that adds wiki functionality?

I have first hand experience with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) and [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) and openly recommend both of them. We've recently switched from Trac to Redmine where I work and I think I like it a little more than Trac, and use the wiki functionality almost everyday.

**Update:**

If you are looking for something smaller scale, there was a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526212/best-personal-desktop-wiki) here on SO that looks like it has some interesting links.

Comment: Is there an offline app that can do collaborated snippets?

Comment: You can set up Trac on an internal web server or even running off your own machine.

Comment: Your link to the previous discussion seems to have been removed. I get "This question was removed from Super User for reasons of moderation.".

Comment: That's an unfortunate side effect of the relentless moderation on stackoverflow sites. They should never delete information, just flag it somehow so it doesn't normally show up in searches. I linked to that article 6 years ago so it had a good run :)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in **[snip2code](http://www.snip2code.com)**.

[image]

They do exactly what you are talking about... searching, collecting and sharing snippets of any language. It solves the problems I had for similar issue.

Hope it may help

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [gist.github.com](http://gist.github.com/). This is definitely much better than a wiki sharepoint.
Plus you can reuse snippets from other user.
Wiki were designed to share any type of content. Some tools have been specifically designed to share code snippets. Some IDEs also have snippet features. 
A wiki is definitely not the best match because it will not integrate with your IDE requiring you to have a separate tool open.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going back and forth between a few Mac applications (haven't decided on one yet but I have tried quite a few).  Most of these options allow you to host your snippet library on Dropbox or another network storage location so you can share your library with others.  I don't know of any that provide any sort of live changes monitoring though.

### [Text Expander](https://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html)

Though not designed as an actual code snippet application, I used this for that purpose for a while and was quite content with it.  You can share your library with others whether they're on Mac or Windows because there is a compatible alternative for Windows (i forget the name of the Windows alternative but it's easily found on Google I'm sure)

Finally decided to move on because I just wanted something a bit more robust.  But may be an option to consider for some.

### [Codebox](http://www.shpakovski.com/codebox/)

[image]

---

### [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash)

I just learned about this one and actually only just started trying it.  So far it's pretty good and I haven't decided whether or not I'll stick to this or go back to Codebox.  I really like the documentation library functionality it has but as far as storing snippets, with my limited experience thus far, all I can say, is I'm rather disappointed in the codehighlighting.  It also doesn't have additional fields to write comments like some of the other applications do so your comments have to actually be written with the code.  I can't say that bothers me though, it's actually a good thing.

[image]

---

### [Snippets](http://www.snippetsapp.com/)

I was using this one for a while and liked it quite a lot but wanted something that I could not only store small snippets in but also full source files like a few self contained javascript libraries.  I attempted to store a large javascript file and the program not only couldn't handle it, but it actually corrupted my entire snippet library which I was hosting on Dropbox.  Not sure if it was a self contained problem because I immediately uninstalled the app after that.  But overlooking that i

[image]

---

### A few others I may try but have no opinion about thus far

[Code Bank (open-source)](https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/silverstripe-codebank)

[Code Collector Pro](http://www.getcodecollector.com/)

---

Last but not least.. I've actually just been using [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dreamcc) more and more lately.  I'm not aware of any desktop application for Gist (there's a browser app for Chrome I think and a couple of third party applications on the AppStore but I haven't tried them)